# Can't get Recalbox to pair with my Apple wireless(bluetooth) keyboard 2011

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, recalbox

I have a raspberry pi 3 running Recalbox v6.0 and an apple wireless keyboard 2011.  I cannot get Recalbox to pair with the keyboard.  I have read some posts which suggest you have to unpair the keyboard with any previous devices, but I cannot do this (the laptop it originally paired with no longer works).

I found a page which recommended connecting the keyboard to another Mac, then unpairing it, powering it down, then long-holding on the power key whilst pairing to a new device.  So I tried this whilst doing the following on the Pi:

SSH'd into the pi, then:

```
sudo service bluetooth status  # Verify bluetooth is active.
bluetoothctl              # Lauch bluetooth subshell.
agent on                       # [No idea what this does.]
default-agent                  # [No idea what this does.]
scan on                        # Displays a list of available devices.
pair 60:C5:47:16:3D:A3         # This prepares a potential connection, the X's represent your device ID
# A "PIN code" will be displayed, type it on the keyboard and press "enter".
trust 60:C5:47:16:3D:A3        # Adds device to trusted devices, this survives reboot.
connect 60:C5:47:16:3D:A3      # Connect to the device now.
exit                           # Return to previous shell.
```

(where 60:C5:47:16:3D:A3 is the ID of my keyboard).

This appeared to almost work once  - I got as far as entering the PIN code, but then it failed, and each time I tried again, I got the error

```
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
```

even after reboots and repairing/unpairing from the Mac.

Any suggestions appreciated. If I need a USB bluetooth dongle, please suggest known working models with the Pi3 and the apple keyboard.